# Token.objects not found

Tags: python, django

I'm using djangorestframework in django==2.0
with python 3.7

I put an event like this

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

when I tried to create a user the compiler giving an error:

```
Exception Value:    
type object 'Token' has no attribute 'objects'
```

Comment: read the docs "Note that you'll want to ensure you place this code snippet in an installed models.py module, or some other location that will be imported by Django on startup." That should be the thing thats breaking. Otherwise, please show your project's structure.  Also don't import inside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do the following

```
>>> from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
>>> Token.objects.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'Token' has no attribute 'objects'
```

If the above error occurs, That's because you didn't add the auth token in the settings' INSTALLED_APPS.
if it's not the in the INSTALLED_APPS, it's abstract and doesn't have the default manager (objects).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `Token` model is not created. So make sure you followed the installation in the documentation.

Make sure you have `'rest_framework.authtoken'` in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Also, rest framework authentication classes inside `settings.py`

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
),
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
)
```

}

Also, make sure you do `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate` which create the `Token` model

Answer (score 0):

First check whether you have added `'rest_framework.authtoken'` under INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py. Then run 'python manage.py migrate'.

Secondly you should open new python shell while creating token for users without token as follows:

```
>>> `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`
>>> `from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token`
>>> `user = User.objects.get(pk=1)`                        
>>> `Token.objects.create(user=user)`
```

<Token: efa5fc4a8b142cd20478a7baaf9d763be44d6acc>